# FSC: Container elements

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, fluid-styled-content

I've used many different container solutions in the past, including FluidTYPO3's FCEs, DCE, gridelements and some more.

I primarily use the functionality of providing container elements that lets the backend user nest content elements in the page module.

But what I haven't seen so far is a solution with core functionality. Shouldn't it be possible to provide container elements via FSC? Does anyone know how to solve e.g. a two-column container element?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested structures is a missing core functionality but has nothing to do with FSC (fluid_styled_content), because FSC is just an frontend element renderer. It can be replaced by other renderers like the old css_styled_content. Nested structures are more complex because they have affects on database structure and backend handling (dragNdrop, translation, work spaces).
So there is at this moment no other way to use an extension like flux, gridelements, templavoila, ...

Answer (score 1):

Per default TYPO3 has no container elements. The `gridelements` is the way to go. That's state of the art.

Or you have a look at the extension `mask` which also brings container elements into TYPO3.